# Google sheets referencing by name, and "custom" history

Tags: google-sheets, history

I've had a [sign up calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7WO4.jpg) running for a community for several years now and there have been two issues I have not been able to solve. I'd love if anyone had a solution for either.

1. In the code I have the main sheet [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7WO4.jpg) where people sign up and then a hidden secondary sheet [0] that this main sheet grabs formatting from when it's resetting for the week. This works great--but if a user accidentally adds a new sheet the code gets messed up since apparently the 0 designation is taken over and the code will reference THEIR sheet until it is deleted. Is there a way to either A) Stop people from adding new sheets entirely, or B) reference the sheet by name instead of number? I'm currently using:

   var sheetFrom =SpreadsheetApp.openById('url').getSheets()[0];

for the hidden sheet but I'd love to just call it by it's name "Script Stuff" instead since that would keep everything from breaking every time someone misclicks.

2. Due to this being an old document the sheet history has gotten very laggy/unusable, but the community needs that edit history. Online it seems like the only solution people have to this is just to make a new sheet and copy everything over, but that isn't feasible in this particular situation due to the sheer amount of users that would need to be informed of the change yearly. I was thinking about just making my own off-the-shelf history by copying new edits and transferring them over to a new hidden sheet (that way I could purge the history whenever I need to). But I haven't been able to figure it out. I already have code set to run at the end of the day resetting everything, so theoretically I just need to add code that copies the data to the new sheet before the calendar resets. How would I do that so it copies it in a continuous column downwards like [this example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzVGu.jpg)? I feel like using code for "copy if cell is filled" applies here somehow but I haven't been able to wrap my head around it.

Existing code:

```
function clearsundayRange() {
  
  // Clears Sunday after it ends.

  sheet.getRange('C7:C54').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('D7:D54').clearContent();
  
  //Fixes background formatting
  
  var valuesToCopy = sheetFrom.getRange("C7:C54");
  Logger.log(valuesToCopy.getValues());
  var range = sheetTo.getRange("C7:D54");
  range.copyTo(valuesToCopy);
  
  // Updates date to one week out

  date.setDate(date.getDate() - 1 + 7);
  var day = date.getDate();
  var month = date.getMonth() +1;
  var year = date.getYear(); 
  var cell = sheet.getRange("C4");
  cell.setValue("=DATE(" + year + "," + month + "," + day + ")");}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

```
var sheetFrom =SpreadsheetApp.openById('url').getSheetByName('Script Stuff');
```

Second question, you just need to copy the contents to the new sheet.  This can be done by:

- Get then name of the sheet, or if keeping in a separate file, get the id of the file.
- Get the last row of the target sheet
- Get the range to be copied
- Get the range to be pasted into
- Copy to the paste range

Comment: When I try the solution for 1) I get an error message "Cannot find function openById" . If I revert it back to the 0 the code runs fine, though.

Thanks for the suggestions on 2)! I'll mess around with that and see if I can get it work. =)

Comment: EDIT 1) Okay so it turns out I just mistyped it. Typing your suggestion correctly lets the function run--but it doesn't seem to be working because it no longer copies from the hidden sheet like it should be. Reverting the code back to 0 makes it copy like normal. SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Script Stuff') did not work either

Comment: Can you post your full code, I would like to see the usage of calling the specific sheet.

Comment: Sure, here's the topmost reference portion. After that it just runs through each individual day (one day already typed up above, the others are basically the same):


var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('url');
var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.openById('url').getSheets()[0];
var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.openById('url').getSheets()[1];
var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheets()[0];
var date = new Date();